# Beginning on the Dulzaina

Tags: learning, self-learning, woodwinds, learning-resources

I'm keen to receive advice or tips on how one can start out with the Spanish wind instrument the Dulzaina (in Catalan it is called the Dolçaina).

[Dulzaina on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulzaina)

Since we're not in Spain we don't have access to local teachers. Given it's supposed similarity to other instruments ([listed here](https://musical-instruments.findthedata.com/q/471/1722/What-is-the-Dulzaina-made-out-of)) would it be feasible to work of some of the resources for similar instruments?

So far, my wife who has a lot of (not recent) experience with the clarinet struggles with it a bit, whereas my ten-year-old daughter plays it somewhat instinctively, just like she plays a recorder and with a similar level of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a double reed, single reed technique like the clarinet will not help you. If you can't find an instructor specifically for the Dulzaina, you could look for other similar double reed instrument teachers to get you started on the reed technique.

The Zurna, Bombard, or an Oboe teacher could start you on the reed technique. Depending on the music stores in your area you can probably rent an oboe for a short time to get started.  Instrument rentals are available through the internet now as well.

As you pointed out about your daughter, picking up a recorder or other similar instrument will get you started with fingering. You could look at the bagpipe practice chanter or the penny whistle for a fairly simple start. While not always directly translatable, fingering and reed technique should be similar enough to get you started in the right direction.